# Can I read raw POST data with Ocamlnet CGI?

Tags: cgi, ocaml

I'm writing some web services using Ocamlnet. More specifically, I'm using Netcgi_scgi in combination with Apache 2.

It looks like all of the functionality is directed at presenting me with an already-parsed view of the user input.

Is there any way for me to access the input stream directly so I can parse the raw POST data myself?

Also, is there a way for me to prevent the Netcgi code from automatically trying to parse the POST data? (I found that, the way I'm doing it, it fails and throws an exception if it doesn't receive the expected key-value format, so my handler never even gets called.)

I would ideally like to be able to support [JSON-RPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification), which calls for the POST data to be a JSON object with no argument name associated with it. (Well, the spec is not protocol specific so that isn't spelled out, but it seems to me to be the most reasonable interpretation.  The old (1.2) spec explicitly shows it done that way.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [The correct way to use Ocamlnet 3 - Http\_client.Convenience.http\_post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047223/the-correct-way-to-use-ocamlnet-3-http-client-convenience-http-post)

Comment: @PaulSweatte: That question is about making POST requests with the HTTP client. It's really not related to what I'm doing at all. I'm on the server parsing requests, he's on the client composing them. He's sending his request to Google so the server in his case isn't even written in OCaml.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way would be (using plex) allowing `application/json` mime

```ml
Nethttpd_plex.nethttpd_factory
  ~config_cgi:Netcgi.({
  default_config with
  default_exn_handler = false;
  permitted_input_content_types = [
    "application/json";
  ] @ default_config.permitted_input_content_types})
```

Then you will get content of request in single parameter `BODY` (if client properly sends `Content-Type: application/json` header), so you can do something like

```ml
let get_json_request (cgi : Netcgi.cgi_activation) =
  cgi # argument_value "BODY"
  |> Yojson.Basic.from_string

let generate_page (cgi : Netcgi.cgi_activation) =
  get_json_request cgi |> process_json_request
```

A little harder (but probably better) way would be providing your own `dyn_activation` and `dyn_handler` for your handler or creating new service (look for `default_dynamic_service` in ocamlnet source)... but I newer went down that path...

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I need. It's been a long time since I touched this project, though (it's an old question) so I won't be able to test it out right away.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cgi_argument`:

```
let with_arg arg f = Io.unwind ~protect:(fun arg -> arg#finalize ()) f arg

let get_arg cgi name =
  try  Some (with_arg (cgi#argument name) (fun arg -> arg#value))
  with Not_found -> None

let parse ?default ~validate ~parse cgi name =
  match default, get_arg cgi name with
  | None  , None    -> argf "Missing parameter \"%s\"" name
  | Some v, None    -> v
  | _     , Some p  ->
    try  parse (Pcre.extract ~rex:validate ~full_match:false p)
    with Not_found -> argf "Invalid parameter \"%s\"" name
```

**References**

- [Netcgi:cgi_argument](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/ocamlnet-4.0.1/doc/html-main/Netcgi.cgi_argument-c.html)
- [How to Write a Simple Web Application using Ocamlnet](http://alaska-kamtchatka.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-write-simple-web-application.html)

Comment: It's been a long time now since I've looked at Netcgi, so I can't be sure about this without testing (which I haven't had time for yet); but this doesn't look like a solution to me problem. This looks like the code that I already had, which does not work. Thanks for the second link though, it looks like a useful article.